# UITableView frame

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

Yesterday, I caught a weird problem.

I add a `UITableView` into a `UIView`. I set frame for `UIView` with height which has a fraction (e.x 631.333). I cannot scroll the `UIView` (in iPad3). I just remove the fraction, the `UITableView` can be scrolled normally.

Does someone know why this happens?

Comment: I don't think there is anything like this..

Comment: @iphonic But it happended to me. Poor me! I set the frame for UIView with height 2.0*CONSTANT/3.0 => I cannot scroll down the UITableView. I just cast it to int. It worked normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your fractioned Rect to Integral using this method:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0.23, 300.77, 425.87));
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I know about CGRectIntegral.However, it is not my concerning thing. I want to know why the fractioned Rect make UITableView can't be scrolled down.